# Remapping keys for workspaces in Xmonad

Tags: configuration, key-mapping, xmonad, workspaces

Xmonad uses

1) <kbd>Mod</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>  for switching to workspace 2
 2) <kbd>Mod</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> for moving window to workspace 2

How would you remap 1) to <kbd>Mod</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> and 2) to <kbd>Mod</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> 
in `~/xmonad/xmonad.hs`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it, but it's not particularly pleasant (and don't forget that in the default configuration, `M-k` and `MS-k` are already used to cycle between windows and move windows around in the stack order - you probably don't want to mask those functions).

What follows is based on a brief look at the source in XMonad/Config.hs. You will need to import `XMonad.StackSet`:

```
import qualified XMonad.StackSet as W
```

and in your keybindings, you want a couple of lines like this:

```
, ((0 .|. modMask, xK_k), windows $ W.greedyView "2")
, ((shiftMask .|. modMask, xK_k), windows $ W.shift "2")
```

Note that unless you explicitly remove the bindings for (or rebind) `M-2` and `MS-2`, they'll still behave as before.