# Remapping keys for physical screens in xmonad

Tags: xmonad

I have a setup with a laptop at the left and two monitors with different resolution at the center and on the right. arandr correctly shows the relative locations too.

However, Mod+w switches to the center monitor and Mod+e switches to the laptop monitor(which is on the left). Only Mod+r correctly switches to the right side. I get the same behavior with shift too.

What configuration should I change to fix this?

--

I'm using a someone else's setting from [here](https://github.com/bsnux/xmonad-config/blob/master/mate/xmonad.hs) with very slight modifications for swing(intellij) and some launcher keys. My config is [here](https://gist.github.com/yoo-haemin/f7e22ac3d47aae22a06723ed271926d3).

I'm using Ubuntu xenial with Mate.

I've read [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68691/remapping-keys-for-workspaces-in-xmonad) answer and the docs of XMonad.StackSet but I still have no idea how to apply that in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I plugged the monitors out and plugged them back in again, and the keys are fixed.

It seems the order you plug them in matters.

added:

It's embarrassing to admit I didn't read the FAQ fully. It's an easy fix.
[link](https://wiki.haskell.org/Xmonad/Frequently_asked_questions#Screens_are_in_wrong_order)